# align the elements inside the container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I don't understand how I can get the correct positioning inside the container.

I need to have the text on the left and the photo on the right and on a small device triggered flex-direction:column; when the picture down stretched. hint please.
I somehow do not get either the text behind the photo goes when it should not be so or some nonsense turns out. I'm just learning.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    position: absolute;
}
.wrappper {
  
    width: 800px;
  height: 500;
  padding: 2vmin;
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.text h1 {
  font-size: 17px;
}
.text p {
  font-size: 15px;
}
.text a {
      text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px 25px;
    border-radius:10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
}
.photo img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrappper">
    <div class="text">
    <h1>Test text</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id modi maxime sit dolorem tempora! Ea porro ipsum earum perspiciatis maiores, distinctio, accusamus voluptatibus repellat magni sint exercitationem quia. Tenetur, porro!</p>
    <a href="#!">test button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://framerusercontent.com/images/CMlJeFc6gnfpf0Q18wwTFJ570Vw.png" alt="">
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use media-queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media and style the elements according to the size of the screen

Comment: I need to center everything. I don't need a media query

Comment: You need your html behave differently on different screen-sizes - you definitely need media-queries. As well as you need to learn about flex https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex and especially about 'align-items' and forget about using 'position: absolute', if you do not need to rip your element out of the context

Answer (score 0):

## Layout Desktop

You can achive at least the start of what you're looking for here just using flexbox and `width`. Using a flexbox row alongside `width: 50%` for your contents should achive the two column effect you're looking for.

## Layout Mobile

[Through media queries you can achive changing the flex direction and the content widths based on the viewport width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries#targeting_media_features).

## Example Stylesheet

Hopefully this minimal example can give you something to expand from.

```
.wrappper {
    width: 800px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

.text {
    width: 50%;
}

.photo {
    width: 50%;
}

.photo img {
    width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .wrappper {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .text {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .photo {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use grid system for responsiveness.